# Using nested for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a specification as below:

> Write a program that prints out all the permutations of two numbers that add up to 7. Hint: you can use two nested for loops.

I have done this but I know this is not correct. What numbers should I put in?

```
public class NestedFor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
      for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.println(i+ "   " +j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [permutations and nested for loops in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567213/permutations-and-nested-for-loops-in-java)

Comment: You also need to check if the numbers i, j add up to 7

Comment: not a duplicate, this time code was provided

Comment: Also, by pretty much universally accepted convention, make your class name CamelCase, starting with a capital latter.

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: I think they wanted to say "all permutations of two positive numbers", because otherwise you'd get too many permutations - in fact, you can get as many as you wish :-)

Comment: @RossDrew i think the idea is that op edits his original post instead of reposting an edited version, so it is a duplicate

Comment: Can he do that if it's "On Hold"?

Comment: @RossDrew that is the whole idea of "On hold" "edit" and "reopen" i think

Comment: Never seen it done so I have no idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NestedFor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
      for(int j=1; j<i; j++) {
        if (i + j == 7 ) {
          System.out.println(i+ "   " +j);
        }
      }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: (5,2) missing. And that's just an example.

Comment: @user3099447 I hope, for your own good, you realize that in the other question you asked about the 7 sum issue, when someone recommended you to use nested for loops for this, they were joking and taking advantage of your seeming ignorance of the matter. Please start learning, that is the only way you get better. Baby steps.

Comment: @arvaladze This does not work properly. It will not display the permutations where i<j (1,6 2,5 3,4). Also, using two for loops to do this is absurd.

Answer (score 8):

Try this (I am assuming you want non-negative numbers, otherwise you have infinite possibilities):

```
for(int i=0; i<=7, i++)
{
   System.out.println(i + "+" + (7-i));
}
```

No need for two for loops.

If instead of non-negative you require positive numbers, this would become:

```
for(int i=1; i<7, i++)
{
   System.out.println(i + "+" + (7-i));
}
```

Comment: The only stylistic change that I'd make is to add parentheses around `7-i`. Aside from that though, this is a nice and concise solution!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Here are the things that you need to consider:

- Assuming that the numbers are required to be positive, the outer loop should go from `1` to `6`, inclusive, not from `1` to `3`.
- Numbers do not need to be in order. Hence, you should not stop the inner loop at `i`, also going from `1` to `6`, inclusive
- You need to add an `if` check before printing `i` and `j`.

Once you fix the three things above, your program should work. Good luck!

Comment: @ssssteffff You do want to get both `1+6` and `6+1`, otherwise it wouldn't pick up some of the [*permutations*](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/permutation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your loops should both loop between 1 and 7. Then inside the last for loop you need to check if the sum of i and j equals 7. If it does, print those two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need a nested loop.

```
for (ii = 0; ii<8; ii++) {
  System.out.printf("(%d, %d)\n",ii,7-ii);
}
```

Keep it simple.

I know the "hint" said you could use two nested loops; but in my experience a little bit of cleverness should not be ignored. When your problem gets much larger, being O(n) rather than O(N^2) is a huge difference...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of adjustments: I'm taking the liberty of posting a solution but please make sure you understand it!

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7/*Need to consider all numbers from 0 to 7*/ ; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i /*Don't overoptimise: this is good enough and will not generate duplicates*/; j++) {
            if (i + j == 7){
                System.out.println(i+ "," +j);
            }
     }
}
```

It's not the fastest way; spend some time optimising once you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){ //First Loop
    for(int j=7;j>0;j--){//Send loop
        if((i+j)==7) System.out.println(i+" , "+j); //Permutations printed to terminal
    }
}
```

I guess it's self explaining, two loops going towards each other. Run it and see the lovely result ;)

> In mathematics, the notion of permutation relates to the act of permuting (rearranging) objects or values.

Comment: The same code can be ran with one loop:
    for(int i=0, j=7;i<7;i++,j--){
        if((i+j)==7)
            System.out.println(i+" , "+j);
}

Answer (score 0):

Check if they add up to 7

```
if (i+j == 7)
{
  //then they add to 7
}
```

They should both be between 1 and 7 though if you want all numbers between 1 and 7 that add up to 7.  If you want to include 0 then start there.

```
 for (int i=1; i<=7; i++)
```

...and you may want to exclude duplicates

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
  for(int j=i; j<=7; j++) { //starts at i, not 1
   /* Only check j against numbers equal to or lower than itself
   /* to avoid duplicates
    */
  }
}
```

**Additionally**

Class names should start with a capitol letter, by convention, and in camel case (each word in a phrase has capitol letters

```
NestedFor
```